Cannot get wireguard to connect

I'm trying to turn my pi into a home VPN with wireguard, but cannot get it to work, despite not receiving any errors.
My pi is connected to my home router via Ethernet cable, and is given ip 192.168.1.35, I can confirm the pi receives internet by running ping www.ao.com from within the pi
My laptop has its own separate internet.
My wireguard /etc/wireguard/ config files are
Pi wg0.conf
[Interface]
PrivateKey = PI_PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 192.168.0.1
 
[Peer]
PublicKey = LAPTOP_PUBLIC_KEY
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.2
ListenPort = 51820



Laptop wg0.conf
[Interface]
PrivateKey = LAPTOP_PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 192.168.0.2
 
[Peer]
PublicKey = PI_PUBLIC_KEY
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.1
Endpoint = ROUTER_IP:51820

Running wg-quick up wg0 on each device returns
pi
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 192.168.0.1 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
[#] ip -4 route add 192.168.0.2/32 dev wg0

laptop
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 192.168.0.2 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
[#] ip -4 route add 192.168.0.1/32 dev wg0

Running ip a confirms wg0 iface is up on both devices.
Running sudo wg doesn't show any handshake information or data stats.
Why cant my laptop connect to my pi VPN?
Ive spent 2 days on this problem.

One end has to contact the other. The normal setup would be that the "pi" listens and the laptop connects, and this is what appears to be the case with your files. What you need is to ensure that the internet router 83.1.230.55 is forwarding tcp port 51820 to the pi (192.168.1.35.  This is in the router configuration, Also check that the laptop can at least ping 83.1.230.55.

@icarus what doesnt make sense is that when wg-quick up wg0 is applied to both machines, the laptop has internet but not through the VPN... I would have assumed that a false-connection to a non-working VPN server would result in a broken inet on the laptop. its dangerous because the user of the laptop can browse net under the belief hes connected through the VPN(which is up in according to cmd ip a, but its not.

your laptop is configure to only allow 192.168.0.1 through the VPN ... so of course it doesn't have internet connection through the VPN ... in your previous question you had AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0 on the "server", that should be on the client ... of course, then you also need to set NAT on the "server" wireguard setup (postUp) and of course remove it (postDown)

All this also assumes you've forwarded port 51820 on the router the pi ("server") uses - and also, if both "server" and "client" are NAT'd, you'll want to set PersistentKeepalive on the "client"

@JaromandaX I havnt been able to port forward yet on the router, I will add
PersistentKeepalive on the client. Do you know why my laptop internet continues to work despite the wg interface being up. I thought the vpn would cut off any leaking traffic.
If not, are you aware of any simple config parameter to cut traffic if connection to vpn server is not active(or faulty)?
Also, does my simple config look like it would work correctly on a setup not requiring port forwarding? Trying to eliminate problems here...

despite the wg interface being up - it's not up if Running sudo wg doesn't show any handshake information or data stats.

If the "server" is NAT'd, then of course you'll need to port forward to it - how else will it receive the connection?

@JaromandaX Ive port forwarded the pi to 51820 in my BT HUB Router, wireguard still doesn't work. I'm completely lost on what to try now...
Can you confirm if the IP address of my PI(assigned from my BT Hub Router DHCP), should match the Address under [Interface] of my PI /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf?

@JaromandaX Re your comment it's not up if Running sudo wg doesn't show any handshake I referred to it as up because when I run ip a I can see the wg0 interface.

I meant it's not connected :p

Can you confirm if the IP address ... should be the Pi's local address

"port forwarded the pi to 51820" ... did you mean you've forwarded port 51820 to the pi in you Router

@JaromandaX Ive configured my router so that it always assigns my pi(via its MAC address) a static private ip of 192.168.1.35, also in the router within the port forward section, ive added and enabled  192.168.1.35 with port 51820. Is it possible for you to upload your two wg0.conf files, sanitizing the Endpoint IP and p*keys?

Sure - https://pastebin.com/5ZiHfrGs

Please don't repost the same question. Fix the original (or delete it if you must). You've now split your audience

I think you should take small steps. You say you now have port forwarding set up. I think the first think to do is test this. I suggest you install socat on both the pi and the laptop. Make sure wireguard is down on both. On pi run "socat TCP4-LISTEN:51820 -" then on the laptop run "socat -d2 TCP:83.1.230.55:51820 -". You should see some messages including a "successfully connected" one and be able to type things on one machine (e.g. hello) and see them on the other. Ctrl-d to close the connection. Then continue with the next step...

.... At this point we know port forwarding is set up correctly. Now to see if wireguard is listening correctly. Bring up wireguard on the pi, and repeat the "socat -d2 TCP:83.1.230.55:51820 -" command on the laptop. Check you still see a successfully connected message.

In the pastebin you posted, in the client you have a Endpoint = server_ip:51820 line. Can you confirm that it actually has either a real name or it has 83.1.230.55 rather than the literal string server_ip?

@ChrisDavies This clearly isn't the same question, The first question spoke about wireguard breaking internet entirely, this current question the internet works but isn't being routed. This question is better structured and more concise.
